# Wrangle authors full name to published type (Full name, First name initial)

Tags: python, string, list

I have a column in a dataset with the following authors full names, Last Name, First Name;

```
Input:
Makarenko, Iuliia; Mazhnaya, Alyona; Marcus, Ruthanne; Pykalo, Iryna; Madden, Lynn; Filippovich, Sergii; Dvoriak, Sergii; Altice, Frederick L.
```

I want to sort the strings so as to have the following, Last Name, Fist initial of first name;

```
Makarenko I, Mazhnaya A, Marcus R, Pykalo I, Madden L, Filippovich S, Dvoriak S, Altice FL
```

I have tried to split the string on `.split(";") and now want to just select the first char from the first name to keep with the last name, I don't know whether I should use a string or list method to do this though.

Comment: Can you please share what code you've written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the following should suffice.
You are correct in starting with splitting by the ";". You can then within a list comprehension split the names further into first and last. This creates a list of lists. We can then sort by the last name and print out what we want as a result.

```
names = [name.split(", ") for name in input_string.split(";")]
names.sort(key=lambda name:name[1])
print(", ".join(["{last} {initial}".format(last=name[1], initial=name[0][0]) for name in names]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to re-arrange your string without any kind of "sort".

Try:

```
authors = "Makarenko, Iuliia; Mazhnaya, Alyona; Marcus, Ruthanne; Pykalo, Iryna; Madden, Lynn; Filippovich, Sergii; Dvoriak, Sergii; Altice, Frederick L."
>>> ", ".join(f"{author.split(', ')[0]} {author.split(', ')[1][0]}" for author in authors.split(";"))
'Makarenko I,  Mazhnaya A,  Marcus R,  Pykalo I,  Madden L,  Filippovich S,  Dvoriak S,  Altice F'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sample of desired results you provided if there is a person with a middle name, then the initials of the first and the middle name are joint together. If this is what you want to get then you can try the following:

```
s = "Makarenko, Iuliia; Mazhnaya, Alyona; Marcus, Ruthanne; Pykalo, Iryna; Madden, Lynn; Filippovich, Sergii; Dvoriak, Sergii; Altice, Frederick L."

names = [name.split(", ") for name in s.split(";")]
names = [name[0].strip() + " " + "".join(n[0] for n in name[1].split()) for name in names]
out = ", ".join(names)
print(out)
```

If gives:

```
Makarenko I, Mazhnaya A, Marcus R, Pykalo I, Madden L, Filippovich S, Dvoriak S, Altice FL
```